# Gaussian Elimination Using Fortran

Tags: linear-algebra, fortran

I developed the code below for performing gaussian elimination in order to evaluate the determinant of a matrix:

```
program det3


REAL, DIMENSION(3,3) :: matriz = RESHAPE([1,2,3,-7,13,5,4,-21,8],[3,3])
REAL :: temp, m
INTEGER :: n = 3
INTEGER :: i, j, k
INTEGER :: fator_cor = 1
REAL :: det

DO k=1, n-1

    DO i = k+1, n

                IF (matriz(k,k) == 0) THEN
                    linha_aux = matriz(k,0:n)
                    matriz(k,0:n)= matriz(k+1, 0:n)
                    matriz(k+1,0:n)= linha_aux
                    fator_cor = fator_cor*(-1)



                END IF

    END DO


END DO


    DO j = k+1, n
            m = matriz(j,k)/matriz(k,k)

            DO i = k+1, n
                matriz(j,i) = matriz(j,i) - m*matriz(k,i)



            END DO



    END DO




det = l
    DO i = 1, n
        det = det * matriz(i,i)
        det = det*fator_cor
    END DO

WRITE (*,*) det







end program
```

I'm trying to apply it to the 3x3 matrix declared in the beginning but I'm getting the error:

> "Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)"
>   linha_aux = matriz(k,0:n)"

I'm a bit new to fortran so I'm not sure what it is refering to. I'm unsure if I should declare linha_aux at all, and if so if I should declare it as an allocatable array. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note question would be more suitable for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Some (bit to to long for a comment) initial remarks:

You try to assign an array `matriz(k,0:n)` to a scalar integer variable `linha_aux`. `linha_aux` is a scalar integer variable as it is implicitly declared.

- declare all variables
- use IMPLICIT NONE so you have to declare all variables
- Fortran starts counting elements at 1, so `matriz(k,0:n)` has a
  problem as `n` is declared as 3 and the matrix has size 3 times 3.
- the nested loops:

  ```
  DO k=1, n-1

     DO i = k+1, n
  ```

  as the content of the loop does not use `i` and also in `matriz(k+1,0:n)`the matrix would go out of bounds on the first index (and and the second due to the 0).
- note that Fortran has column major order (so the first index runs
  fasts), this ordering is other than e.g. C that has row major
  ordering.